# How does the "in" operator work with non-string keys?

Tags: javascript, operators, in-operator

When I use `in` operator in javascript, I find something strange. It seems that `in` uses a similar rule as `==` but not the same. Here are some tests:

```
var obj = {1: 'a', 3: 'b'};
1 in obj     //=> true
'1' in obj   //=> true
[1] in obj   //=> true
true in obj  //=> false
```

Because `1 == '1' == [1] == true`, so it seems that operand will be cast to string or integer type before comparison with `in` operator except for `boolean`. So I wonder am I right?

Comment: Nothing to do with comparison there. Anyway, this leads to an interesting JavaScript fact: *all* property names are internally strings.

Comment: @user2864740 At least, until [`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) become regularly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. It will first convert the left operand to a string, note however that the rules for converting between various data types in JavaScript are a lot more subtle than you might think.

```
true == "true"   //=> true
true == "1"      //=> true
"true" == "1"    //=> false
```

The precise rules are fairly complicated<sup>*</sup>, but the important thing to remember here is that when a Boolean is converted directly to a string, this is the result:

```
true.toString()  //=> "true"
false.toString() //=> "false"
```

So this is exactly the behavior you should expect, for example:

```
var obj = { "true": "a", "false": "b" };
true in obj      //=> true
false in obj     //=> true
1 in obj         //=> false
```

<sup>* See [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be different contexts.

These check keys, where true isn't a key.

```
1 in obj     //=> true
'1' in obj   //=> true
[1] in obj   //=> true
true in obj  //=> false
```

1 == '1' == [1] == true

This checks bit value where 1 is true.

0 == false should be true.